# problem in building typescript application with imports and type module

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've actually read every stackoverflow post related to my problem, but I can't solve it, every attempt brings me a new problem.

This is the **structure**:
[image]

**package.json**:

```
{
  ..
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-esm ./src/index.ts",
    "start": "ts-node-esm ./src/index.ts",
    "build": "tsc --build",
    "clean": "tsc --build --clean"
  },
...
}
```

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "esnext",
       "noImplicitAny": false,
       "sourceMap": true,
       "resolveJsonModule": true,
       "moduleResolution": "Node",
       "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
       "esModuleInterop": true,
       "outDir": "dist",
   },
   "include": [
    "src/*"
  ]
}
```

**index.ts** imports **myModule.ts** like this:

```
...
import request from 'request';
import {connection} from "../config/db.js";
import { MyModule } from '../assets/ts/myModule.js';
```

I start the development app with this command and everything works fine::

```
npm run dev

> myApp@1.0.0 dev
> ts-node-esm ./src/index.ts
```

now i want to build the application for production.
i wanted to use pm2 but i had several problems.

what is the best approach and the most performing solution to put my application into production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it is currently possible to use the `ts-node-em` command with the `--transpile-only` flag without compromising performance. So it can be used in production:

Solution:

```
ts-node-esm --transpile-only ./src/index.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

I already had an experience with rolling up a project and found out about this fantastic library you can use in this case! [RollupJS](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/)

Comment: is it really that complex to solve the problem? I was hoping it was some quick changes to the config files.
However, even with this library I get this error:  `[!] RollupError: Could not resolve "../assets/ts/myModule.js" from "src/index.ts"`

Comment: it isn't `myModule.js` but `myModule.ts` can you try to change the import path on your `"src/index.ts"`

Comment: Yes, the file is .ts but the import must be .js. If I change the import from .js to .ts the dev command doesn't work either. It is not possible to import .ts files. Anyway I tried and the rollup command replies to me like this: `[!] RollupError: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)`

Comment: Yes, you need the tyescript [rollup-plugin][1]

  [1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package//rollup-plugin-ts

Comment: I created the rollup.config.js file, with this content:
`import ts from "rollup-plugin-ts";
export default {
plugins: [
ts ({
       tsconfig: "tsconfig.json"
})
]
};`

It still gives me the error that I need a plugin.
I also tried removing the import from the `index.ts` file
and in the `tsconfig.json` file I added:
  `
 "includes": [
     "src/*",
     "assets /ts/myModule.ts"
   ]
`
but in the boudle there is no reference to the contents of the myModule file

Comment: well i also tried `tsc -w -p` to compile, i have hundreds of errors. All this complexity in building is embarrassing, I will definitely use `ts-node-esm --transpile-only ./src/index.ts` in production.